# Is it feasible to enhance Google Maps by incorporating drone imagery, similar to satellite views, for improved visualization of locations?

Tags: quadcopters

I've been using Google Maps to scout locations for my drone photography, and it's been incredibly helpful for planning my shots. However, I've been wondering if there's a way for me to contribute more directly to Google Maps with my drone. Specifically, I'm interested in uploading 3D imaging from my drone. I understand that it's possible to upload still images, but I believe that 3D images could provide a much richer experience for users. Is there a process or a platform within Google Maps where I can share these 3D drone images?